# BackboneJS copy model without reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How can I copy BackboneJS model without any reference (just want to copy the attribute values) ?

I have tried using

```
self.origModel.set("attr1",self.model.get("attr1"));
self.model = self.origModel.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a shallow copy:

```
var attributes = model.toJSON();
```

There is no built in way to get a deep copy, but you can use lodash's [cloneDeep()](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep):

```
var attributes = _.cloneDeep(model.attributes);
```

It wasn't entirely clear if you just want just the attributes or a new model with a copy of the attributes. To get a model, use `new Backbone.Model(attributes)`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **model.clone()**? This is the easy option to make model copy.

Comment: yes..i have tried that...but i want to copy without reference...just the values...